# RewriteRule changes URL only when it doesn't end with slash?

Tags: mod-rewrite

This simple rule in `.htaccess` handles languages at my website:

```
RewriteRule "^(de|it|es|fr|en-us)(?:|/(.*))$" "$2?lang=$1" [NC,QSA]
```

It works fine unless I miss slash at the end of URL. Than it changes URL in browser's address bar which is not what I want.

To make myself more clear look at examples bellow.

`http://mydomain/en-us/projects/` keeps that URL in address bar and calls `http://mydomain/projects?lang=en-us` which is OK (+generates `REDIRECT_STATUS=200`).

`http://mydomain/en-us/projects` (notice missing slash at the end) calls same URL but makes change in address bar (it doesn't generate `REDIRECT_STATUS`).

As I have almost zero experience with Apache stuff must ask you how to rewrite any of URLs like

```
http://mydomain/[lang_id]
http://mydomain/[lang_id]/more/dirs/here/
http://mydomain/[lang_id]/test.php
```

to

```
http://mydomain?lang=[lang_id]
http://mydomain/more/dirs/here?lang=[lang_id]
http://mydomain/test.php?lang=[lang_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a question mark after the trailing slash in the rule. End the rewrite rule with `/?$`. Follow this example:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?shop=$1&page=index [NC,L,QSA]
```

For your scenario I believe it would be

```
RewriteRule "^(de|it|es|fr|en-us)(?:|/(.*))?$" "$2?lang=$1" [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Nope... Doesn't work! Anyway, that `?` is not supposed to change anything because entire group is written as `(nothing|something)` so according to how I understand things that group would be ignored if nothing trails [lang_id]. But my knowledge about regex is related to JS/PHP/Ruby regular expressions and I'm sure that Apache handles them in a bit different way. Thanks for your try, anyway.